# Does Rails 4 engine autoload engine's i18n locales file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I got a question about Rails engine, which is not mentioned under Rails guide about Rails engine. I hope to get it here.

I got one engine, for example, called my_engine, and one app, called my_app.

for development purpose, in my_app's Gemfile, I just simple include my_engine with following line, using :file key.

```
#my_app/Gemfile
...
gem "my_engine", :path => "./../my_engine"
...
```

and my_engine structure is like this:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── app
│   ├── ...
|   |...
|
├── config
│   ├── locales
│   │   └── models
│   │       └── products
│   │           ├── en.yml
│   │           └── zh-TW.yml
│   └── routes.rb
├── lib
│   ├── my_engine
│   │   ├── engine.rb
│   │   └── version.rb
│   ├── my_engine.rb
│   └── tasks
│       └── my_engine_tasks.rake
```

And I found that while I try to inspect I18n.load_path under my_app, there's no any single path point to my_engine, which means, my_app doesn't load my_engine's locale transactions.

```
>>rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
2.1.0 :001 >I18n.load_path.each { |x| puts x }
```

Is it I missing some config or some important steps about loading locales in my_engine?

Comment: actually after I read this, I don't understand what you talk about, do you mean rails doesn't load the engine's locales files or?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using

```
Rails 4.1.6
```

and I mounted my engine like this inside Gemfile

```
gem 'core', path: "core"
```

when I check my load paths

```
I18n.load_path.find_all { |p| p.match("core") }.each { |p| puts p }
```

I see locales included from my engine

> /absolute_path/core/config/locales/de.yml
>
> /absolute_path/core/config/locales/en.yml

so as default rails is loading your engine locales

it's also mentioned in documentation

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html

> Then ensure that this file is loaded at the top of your config/application.rb (or in your Gemfile) and it will automatically load models, controllers and helpers inside app, load routes at config/routes.rb, load locales at config/locales/*, and load tasks at lib/tasks/*.

Answer (score -1):

All methods declared in Application Controller are seen from any location. Indicate application which language should be loaded with the code:

```
# on my_app/app/controller/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
   I18n.locale = request.headers['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].split(',')[0].split('-')[0]
end
```

Hope this helps you  Randy Marsh

Comment: The answer may not be clear to some as it only provides source code. Could you edit your post and add some more explanation? Thank you.